# Lists of rules vs. Associations

Tags: import, associations, json-format

It seems that generally, Mathematica users (or at least the Q&A I've read here) prefer associations to represent data in ways that many other languages would use structures.

However, when [Import](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Import.html?q=Import)ing [JSON](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/JSON.html) files, Mathematica generates a list of rules.

Is there any clear advantage one way or the other?  Is it just syntactical?  Is there a reason Mathematica uses lists of rules for JSON instead of associations?

Comment: You can also import as an Association using the "RawJSON" format.

Comment: They're slightly different: for one, lists of rules can have multiple rules of the form `key0 -> value` for the same `key0`, e.g. `{a -> x, b -> y, b -> z}`. But if you convert this into an association, only the last key-value pair for a given key will be kept: `Association[{a -> x, b -> y, b -> z}]` gives `<|a -> x, b -> z|>`. I don't know, but I imagine this might be one reason to maintain a difference.

Comment: `Association` is newer and has several advantages, which are discussed elsewhere on this site. Since it’s newer, old functionality that returned lists may still do so, for the sake of compatibility. They work differently, since `pattern -> replacement` has a different intention than `key -> value`. Thus `Reverse /@ {x -> a, y -> b}` inverts the mapping represented by the list; mapping any function (like `Reverse`) on an association applies the function to each value. Etc. The different semantics make each useful for different applications. `Association` is intended to represent key/value data.